# Alternative for SetKwInParam in algorithm2e

Tags: algorithm2e

In recent versions of algorithm2e SetKwInParam no longer exists:

> REMOVE: - SetKwInParam has been deleted since not useful itself because of different macros which can do the same in a better and a more consistent way as SetKwFunction or SetKw.

So how can I get the same result in the more recent versions of algorithm2e?

For example, I would like to define a new function with 3 parameters, where the function name is in bold face:

**MyFunction(***param1*, *param2*, *param3***)**

Note the bold face 'MyFunction(' and ')'. The parameter might be a math expression.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A minimal file to produce what you want:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algorithm2e}

\begin{document}

\SetFuncSty{textbf}
\SetKwFunction{TestFunc}{MyFunction}
\TestFunc{param1, param2, param3}

\end{document}
```

The output:

[image]

Note that you can use math expressions as parameters, for example:

```
\TestFunc{\(\omega\), \(\omega^2\), \(\omega^3\)}
```

produces:

[image]